# Manipulate inside a function definition slows down when passed a large data set

Tags: manipulate, function-construction, memory

I'm working with large data sets (>1gb) which I'm visualizing with `Manipulate[]`. The following example works fine for me with no additional memory overhead:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {500, 500, 500}];
(* no memory overhead and fast response time *)
Manipulate[Image[data[[All, All, i]]], {i, 1, 500, 1}]
```

However, if I wrap the above code into a separate function definition, memory usage rises and evaluation does'n complete in a reasonable time:

```
vizData[dataVar_] := Manipulate[Image[dataVar[[All, All, i]]],{i, 1, 500, 1}]
(* very high memory usag and slow evaluation! *)
vizData[data]
```

How can I wrap the functionality of `Manipulate` into a function without this high memory utilization? Working with global variables is not an option because I'm dealing with multiple data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to pass the full data set into the `Manipulate`. You just want to pass its name and have it evaluated inside the `Manipulate`. Try the following. Is it fast enough?

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {500, 500, 500}];
SetAttributes[vizData, HoldFirst];
vizData[dataVar_Symbol] := 
  Manipulate[Image[dataVar[[All, All, i]]], {i, 1, 500, 1}]
```

Comment: Works great! When it is advisable to use Hold[] and when not?

Comment: I didn't use `Hold`. I gave your function the attribute `HoldFirst`, which is something different. I did it because `Manipulate` has the attribute `HoldAll`, which made me suspicious about passing in the data by value. I was acting on intuition, not out of a deep understanding of `Manipulate` internals.